# zbar scanner defaults to front camera on android

Tags: android, air, zbar

I'm using ZBAR scanner in the excellent ANE https://github.com/saumitrabhave/qr-zbar-ane in Adobe Air mobile app.

It's working well, but always defaults to the front camera on android.

Any idea where this is set, and how I overrule it to always use the rear camera only?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with s.launch(true,"rear");